# Is it possible to save an image with Core Graphics on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d

The following code converts a PDF page into a JPEG. It runs as expected on Snow Leopard:

```
...
//get the image from the bitmap context
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(outContext);

//create the output destination
CGImageDestinationRef outfile = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(fileUrl, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);

//add the image to the output file
CGImageDestinationAddImage(outfile, image, NULL);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(outfile);
...
```

This code fails when compiled for iPhone because the iPhone version of Core Graphics does not include `CGImageDestinationRef`. Is there any way to save `CFImageRef` to a jpeg using the native iPhone frameworks and libraries? The only alternative I can think of is to ditch Core Graphics and use ImageMagick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9f);
[jpgData writeToFile:...
```